# Write command output to file plus console from another console

Tags: shell, terminal, io-redirection

I am developing a script where I have to run it from the command line (say T1). The script has to open another terminal (T2) and the output of this terminal (T2) has to be redirected to a file, so that I can parse the file from the main script (T1). I know how to open a new terminal (T2) from the main terminal (T1).

```
gnome-terminal -e "ant" 2>&1
```

I also know how to throw command output to file plus console by using tee

```
 ls | tee /home/xyz.txt
```

So I try to run T2 from T1 and redirect T2's output to xyz.txt by doing this:

```
gnome-terminal -e "ant" 2>&1 | tee /home/xyz.txt
```

However xyz.txt doesn't get output from T2.
So how to get the output of T2 to xyz.txt from T1?

Comment: Perhaps you ought to use a terminal emulator with a more mature feature set - for example, `xterm` has an option `-lf <file>` to log all activity to a file. Another alternative would be to run commands under `script`, which logs terminal activity - e.g. `gnome-terminal -e 'script -c ant /home/xyz.txt'`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this sounds very convoluted and looks like an [XY-Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), here's one way to do it (tested with xterm instead of gnome-terminal).

```
gnome-terminal -e "ant | tee $(tty) xyz.txt; read dummy"
```

The `tty` names the terminal device where you start the terminal, not the new terminal. The `read` is optional and waits for ENTER so you see what's on the terminal display.

Comment: Sorry couldn't get back soon enough... I tried the same with xterm and it worked. Thanks! Didn't work with gnome-terminal though.